# Strange variable comparison result - no return

Tags: php, variables, comparison

if

```
echo $obj['URLvideo'];
```

prints **http://domain.com/dir/image.jpg**

and

```
echo "http://domain.com/dir/" . $myimage;
```

prints **http://domain.com/dir/image.jpg**

shouldn't

```
"http://domain.com/dir/" .$myimage == $obj['URLvideo'];
```

return **true** ??

For some reason, it's just returning **NOTHING** for me... I'm stumped, but then, I've been awake for 32 hours.  HELP?

Comment: Are you using one equal or two?

Comment: classical. Use `==` and you're fine. Happens to me always the other way round and I'm wondering why the variable is still not initialized :-/

Comment: try, "http://domain.com/dir/" .$myimage == " . $obj['URLvideo']";

Comment: No sorry - mistyped my problem - I AM using '=='

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing and assignment, not a comparison. Change the single `=` to `==`.

**Edit:** Since you said that you mistyped `==`:

The Problem is then that PHP prints an empty string for booleans.
Do either `echo (int)(expression);` or `echo expression ? "true" : "false";`.
The first will print and integer (0 or 1) and the second, well true or false.

Comment: No sorry - mistyped my problem - I AM using '=='

Comment: Should this return `true` or `1`?

Comment: Thanks - this solution; using `expression ? "true" : "false";` solved more than one problem for me - Absolutely rocking!